# Jquery Modal background overlapping the modal box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a custom modal alert box for a few of my forms and they seem to be working fine, except the modal background seems to be overlapping my modal box...and this is an issue because you can't click on it at all or see it well.

I created a jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JBUqf/2/ but it seems jsfiddel just doesn't like the modal function.

A jsFiddle that actually works! Thanks @Ali http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/208/

My html looks like this

```
 <div class="modal_window" id="authorCover">
   <div class="modal_heading"><h2>Modal Heading</h2></div>
   <div class="modal_content">
     <p>This is the Modal Content Area.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal_footer">
      <button class="modal_close" href="#authorCover">Close</button>
   </div>
 </div>

<button class="btn btn-small btn-danger pull-right modalCall" href="#authorCover">Submit</button>
```

my css looks like this

```
.modal_window{
    display: none;
    background:#fff;
    left:50%;
    margin:-200px 0 0 -40%;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    width:80%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index: 5000;
    padding: 0;
}


.modal_heading{
    background:#F7F7F7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.modal_heading h2{
    margin: 0px;
}
.modal_content{
    padding: 10px;
}

.modal_footer{
    background:#F7F7F7;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and my jQuery looks like this

```
$('.modalCall').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.modal_window').modal();
  return false;
});
```

**I have tried upping the z-index on the modal box as well as trying to lower it on the background that is automatically generated, but it doesn't have any effect.**

I have also tried to put a position absolute on it, which only messed up the styles already placed on the box.

Am I missing something?

Edit: I am not looking for a hide() show() solution. I am trying to use the specific modal() function.

Comment: Define modal function in jquery. There is no standard modal function in jquery

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals I assumed it was jQuery sense it was just working...but on further research it is a bootstrap thing. I did not create it.

Comment: Check this out, http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/9/

Comment: Or this: http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/208/ - I think this is close to the problem you have

Comment: @Ani that is exactly my issue!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/209/ fixed :D

Comment: To follow up with @KristofFeys, add `z-index: 2000`; to `.modal_window`

Comment: @Ani i\If you look at my original post you can see I had already tried that. I think currently the z-index is at 5000

Comment: Your original post has `z-index: 1000;`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ani Yes, but if you read the entire post you will see "I have tried upping the z-index on the modal box as well as trying to lower it on the background that is automatically generated, but it doesn't have any effect." I just updated it to what it currently is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with your modal, but if you remove `display: none`, the modal is displayed (so jsFiddle "likes" your modal ;) ) :

```
 /*display: none;*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JBUqf/3/

If you want to use a modal function, you should look [jqueryui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Look at this [example with a button](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated).

Comment: I mean that is the whole point of a modal. No it does not like the modal() function because what a modal() function does is display the modal.

Comment: And how can I check the background of the modal, which is the issue if I am not running the modal function?

Comment: If you look at the console it gives this error TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#authorCover').modal()')

Comment: I don't think `modal()` is part of jQuery... But I'm maybe wrong because I don't know everything about `jQuery2`.

Comment: Look jqueryui dialog if you don't have any modal plugin. ;)

Comment: It is a boostrap modal, so the function is automatically made.

Answer (score 0):

**Without bootstrap:** you can simply use the jQuery show and hide functions like this:

```
$('.modalCall').on('click', function(){
    $('#authorCover').show();
});
$('.modal_close').on('click',function(){
  $('#authorCover').hide();
});
```

cfr. http://jsfiddle.net/JBUqf/6/

to add an overlay, you can simply use following css:

```
.overlay{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    display:none;
}
```

Simply show or hide this one as well, and boom ... here you have your modal with overlay.

---

**Bootstrap:**
When using bootstrap make sure that the z-index of your modal window is higher then the overlay.
I've checked an the overlay is having `z-index:1030;`. So the modal would need at least `z-index:1031;`, to be on top of the overlay. You can easily check this with your browsers development tools.

cfr. http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/209/

Comment: I would prefer to use the modal() function because it has the built in styles for the background only I am having trouble with that. plus it is much less code and is way more dynamic.

Comment: Add your additional modal jquery file as external resources in the fiddle, get it working and then explain your problem

Comment: but then again, still don't know why any plugin would be needed, added an overlay to the fiddle to let you see how it could be done easily without extra plugin...

Comment: I am not building it, it is being built for me http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Again, I would already like to use what it already there for me instead of adding more code than I have to.

Comment: as explained in the documentation from bootstrap, you need to use the 'show' & 'hide' from the modal...

Comment: @KristofFeys Then how is this working? http://www.devilogs.com/responsive-modal-with-jquery/ and have you read this? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: My bad... apparently it isn't needed. Can you check the example @Ani Showed in the comments? Is that the issue that is occuring? If so you could easily fix it with Z-index

Comment: In my original post I said I had already tried upping the z-index. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/JBUqf/8/ You shouldn't use percentage `margin` if you don't set fixed `dimensions`.

Comment: I was trying to follow this demo http://www.devilogs.com/responsive-modal-with-jquery/ because it seemed cleaner. Why not set percentages..thats much better than setting a fixed pxs responsive wise.

Comment: If you want to have a responsive modal, with percentage based positioning, you need to give the modal same units for each property: `width:80%`, `height:60%`, `margin:0`, `top:20%`, `left:10%`

Comment: @n1kkuo Thats not my issue here though...and what I have works.

Comment: @zazvorniki Is this what are you looking for? The content bg overflowing? http://jsfiddle.net/JBUqf/9/

Answer (score 0):

Okay: Here you go:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NUCgp/210/

```
.modal_window{
   z-index: 2000;
 }
```

Comment: Why did you change the classes in the css to id's? And is there any way to call it on a specific button click? I really don't want to have a modal on all button clicks.

Comment: I changed my answer :) Check again!

Comment: I just copy and pasted that exact code into my app and it's still showing the background in front of the modal box...I even upped the z-index to 5000.

Comment: I think you should replicate your problem on fiddle and post it. People find it hard to understand the problem if they can't see it. And you are more likely to get an answer if you create fiddle.

Comment: Every single bit of code I have is already posted here. And I have created a fiddle...

Comment: But again your fidlde has z-index as 1000 in fiddle but if you make it 2000, it works.

Comment: Just because a fiddle works does not mean it's going to work in a real environment. In the real environment changing the z-index does not work. I can create a youtube vid to show you if you would like.

Comment: Exactly my point, you need to replicate your problem on fiddle. May be the error is somewhere else on the page, but how will people know it, unless you show them a link with error or replicate your problem on fiddle.

Comment: @Ali It is not in my page. I tried stripping everything out except for the button and the modal. But the point I was saying was jsFiddle is not always the solution. Sometimes things work in a fiddle that will not work outside of one and sometimes things work outside a fiddle that do work inside one. It's not the solve all solution. By the way heres a youtube link to my issue http://youtu.be/nTPRVrj419Q